# xslt code implementation..lookup in xml for xpaths

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, ibm-datapower

I have an xml like

```
<xpaths>
<xpath>ns1:body/ns1:request/ns1:name</xpath>
<xpath>ns1:body/ns1:request/ns2:amount</xpath>
<xpath>ns1:body/ns1:response/ns1:address</xpath>
</xpaths>
```

Now I have web sevices running on datapower x152 appliance made on web service proxies. I need to make a general xslt which will check the above xpaths in the incoming req xml by looking into the above xml, if the xpath is there then i need to encrypt the tag and send the xml forward after encrypting the tag with dp encrypt function.
I am ok with the encryption part. I just need some help in how to  implement this logic to lookup the tag and send the xml forward after modifying one tag.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DataPower XST processor is a XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT + many proprietary extension functions and elements processor.

You can dynamically evaluate XPath expressions via EXSLT [dyn:evaluate()](http://exslt.org/dyn/functions/evaluate) function. You can open your above XML file via XSL [document()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function while processing your real XML input.

Hermann.